# Creating a Rich Text Editor in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, richtextbox, flutter-dependencies, rich-text-editor

I am planning to create a rich text editor in Flutter for a personal application. I know there are already some options like zefyr. However, it is still in dev preview and I want to build something a bit different.

The features of the text editor will be that users can add images, bolden text, add lists, italicize text, etc. Just basic text editor things.

Where I am having issues is in the text input side of things. The flutter default text input only allows one style of text per text field. So that would pose a great challenge when it comes to inline styling. Also, a text field cannot have an image inside it, so that is another problem.

If anyone has any ideas on how to go about this, it will be great for a start.

So, I am really asking for the approach to create the editor because it is not as simple as creating one in html

Comment: One advise (based on experience with web rich-text editors, but also from exploring existing options in Flutter): Developing a text editor is (surprisingly) complex. It starts easy as long as you ignore certain things, but then gets tricky very fast. E.g. input methods (e.g. Chinese), RTL input, or even text selection/ copy&paste. Be sure to look at as many other projects as you can (code/ issues) and then decide whether you really want to take on this challenge. I don't want to discourage you, but there are many half-completed editors out there.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you... I figured that I would settle for Zefyr and make some modifications because the time involved is too much for my constraints. Thanks for the answer

Comment: In case Zefyr does not work for you (it's still buggy as of today...), you can also experiment with a webview. Essentially you would create the editor in HTML with inline CSS & JS and communicate with Flutter via the JavaScript Channel.